# How to pass a dynamic variable in ajaxForm

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using query ajaxFrom to submit my form and my code is like this :

```
 (function() {
         $('#modal2From').ajaxForm({

             beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) 
             {
               arr.push( {dataKind:'major', grade: selectedGrade });
             },

             /*dataType: "text",
             data: {
                 dataKind: "major",
                 grade: selectedGrade
             },*/

             beforeSend: function() {

             },

             success: function(msg) {
                 console.log(msg);
             },
             error: function(err) {

             },
             complete: function(xhr) {

             }

         });

     })();
```

The problem is that `selectedGrade` is a dynamic variable and since when i load the page ajax gets call, `selectedGrade` is undefined because the user has not chosen a grade yet so i can't access it by `$_POST['grade']` on php file. 

Note that if i remove `selectedGrade` from `data {}` my code works fine.

Here is HTML code :

```
 <div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer" style="text-align:right;">
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name='modal1From' role="form" id="modal1From" method="post" action="../php/upload.php">
           <div class="modal-content">

                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="file-field input-field col s12 m6 offset-m6 tool tipped">
                        <div class="file-path-wrapper col s9 m9">
                           <input id="modal1FilePath" class="file-path validate" type="text">
                        </div>
                      <div class="btn col s3 m3">
                         <span>Choose</span>
                         <input type="file" name="files" id="modal1FileUpload">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress tooltipped" id="modal1Progress" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="0%" style="top:10px;display:none;">
                       <div class="determinate" style="width:0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                 </div> 
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                  <a href="#!" class="modal-action waves-effect waves-green btn-flat left modalConfirm" type="">Confirm</a>
                  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn stop_upload_btn" style="float:left;display:none;">Stop</a>
                  <a class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat left">close</a>

            </div>

       </form>

  </div>
```

Forms gets submit : `$("#modal1From").submit();` on `. modalConfirm` click

Comment: You can add one if condition to check the selectedGrade before sending the ajax call.

Comment: So dont run ajax when load page ! It will more better to run ajax when user has chosen.

Comment: If use if condition ajaxForm don't work at all ! I don't know why ! i'm not so familiar with ajaxForm

Comment: try setting value of `selectedGrade` in  `beforeSubmit()` or `beforeSend()`

Comment: I did it and still not working its undefined

Comment: show your html code too !!!

Answer (score 0):

E,

bind your ajax() call on some event like,

```
$('button').click(function(){
var val = $('#selectedGrade').val();
if(val != '')
{
   // call ajax
}
else
{
  // show error message
}
});
```

it will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the gradle attributes in beforeSubmit function.

From the ajaxForm docs:

> beforeSubmit: Callback function to be invoked before the form is
>   submitted. The 'beforeSubmit' callback can be provided as a hook for
>   running pre-submit logic or for validating the form data. If the
>   'beforeSubmit' callback returns false then the form will not be
>   submitted. The 'beforeSubmit' callback is invoked with three
>   arguments: the form data in array format, the jQuery object for the
>   form, and the Options Object passed into ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit.

so you can change your beforeSubmit function as follow:

```
beforeSubmit : function(arr, $form, options){
    arr.push( {name:'gradle', value: your-selectedGradle-value })
},
```

Comment: I've edited my code based on your answer but i still get undefined error.

Comment: you have not to use the selectedGrade variable, you have to take the value of the html component, something like $("#gradleId").val() or update the selectedGradle var with the new value and use it